# how to convert array output to normal string in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, string

I am implementing tag functionality and an article may have one to many tags. I am able to get tag values from db in this format

```
["social network", "professional"]
```

I want output in this format

```
"social network professional"
```

I want to convert an array into a string without `,`. Below is a code snippet which takes out values from db as an array.

```
<%= article.tags.collect(&:name) %>
```

How can I convert this output into string value(s) with out any comma?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you look at `pluck`? This if very useful for if you want just one record from the db (in your case 'name'). You could use that to do this:

```
a = article.tags.pluck(:name)
```

To then output your article names separated by spaces do this:

```
a.join(" ")
```

For completeness sake, you can chain these methods (like you said in the comment below) like this:

```
article.tags.pluck(:name).join(" ")
```

Comment: Yes I know, the difference however is on which level both operate. `pluck` operates on the `db` level and `collect` on the array. To see this in action, check your `tail -f /log/development.log` for both cases. With the `collect` method the query returns all fields and then collects the fields you want, with `pluck`, only the db parameter will be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I got two solutions which are below:

```
<%= article.tags.collect(&:name).join(" ")%>
<%= article.tags.pluck(:name).join(" ") %> - by yossarian.
```

Answer (score -1):

["social network", "professional"].join(",")

> "social network,professional"

## or if you don't want the comma

["social network", "professional"].join(" ")

> "social network professional"

Comment: `.join(" ")` has already been mentioned in both existing answers.